# creating a simple function using lists of operators and integers

Tags: python, list, operators

EDIT:  When I say function in the title, I mean mathematical function not programming function.  Sorry for any confusion caused.

I'm trying to create a function from randomly generated integers and operators.  The approach I am currently taking is as follows:

STEP 1:  Generate random list of operators and integers as a list.

STEP 2:  Apply a set of rules to the list so I always end up with an integer, operator, integer, operator... etc list.

STEP 3:  Use the modified list to create a single answer once the operations have been applied to the integers.

For example:

STEP 1 RESULT: [1,2,+,-,2,/,3,8,*]

STEP 2 RESULT: [1,+,2,-,2,/,3,*,8] - Note that I am using the operator command to generate the operators within the list.

STEP 3 RESULT: The output is intended to be a left to right read function rather than applying BODMAS, so in this case I'd expect the output to be 8/3 (the output doesn't have to be an integer).

So my question is:  What function (and within what module) is available to help me combine the list as defined above.  OR should I be combining the list in a different way to allow me to use a particular function?

I am considering changing the way I generate the list in the first place so that I do the sort on the fly, but I think I'll end up in the same situation that I wouldn't know how to combine the integers and operators after going through the sort process.

I feel like there is a simple solution here and I am tying myself up in knots unnecessarily!

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Dom

Comment: can you try to clarify a little more on what you want the function to do? do you want a function that performs random math operations?

Comment: I want the function to interpret a predefined list into a mathematical function read from left to right.  The integers and the operators will be predefined by another part of the program.

Comment: so, you will have a list ex. (1, +, 2, 3, /, 4) would equate to 1+2 and 3/4?  is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not quite, the list will be evaluated according to Int, operator, int, operator... etc  Where it doesn't naturally fall into this format, as per your example, the list value will be dropped until it does, ie I would expect to see 1+2/4, with the 3 dropped from the list.

Comment: so, if you have a list(1, 2, 3, /, 4) you would want it to evaluate to 1/4??

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I want.

Comment: question, if you encounter the end of the list and you have two ints, which one do you want removed from the evaluation?

Comment: The first one encountered.  In all instances the first correct operator/operand is always used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create one list for the ints and one for the operators and them append from each list step by step?

edit: you can first convert your ints to strings then, create a string by using string=''.joint(list) after that you can just eval(string)

edit2: you can also take a look at the Sympy module that allows you to use symbolic math in python

Comment: I would still need to understand how to generate the answer from the list created using your method wouldn't I?  But the list is created by interpreting another randomly created list of binary numbers, so it's not really feasible.

Comment: eval(string) will fail because of priority operation that OP doesn't want here `eval('1+2-2/3*8') == -7/3` and not 8/3. So he need parenthesis to have `eval('((((1+2)-2)/3)*8)')`, yes some of them are useless but it's probably easier to just add them everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments, I'm looking into this now. EDIT:  I've just seen polku's comment, this may explain the problems I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's easier, but an elegant way would be to use a binary tree, where leaves are operands and other nodes are operators. You can directly generate it (without lists) by doing something like this (quick and dirty, probably wrong, but you get the idea) :

```
def generate(root, end_depth, depth):
    root = random_operator()
    right_child = random_operand()
    if depth == end_depth:
        left_child = random_operand()
    else:
        generate(left_child, end_depth, depth + 1)
```

Your example would like this :

```
         *
       /  \ 
     div   8
     / \
    -   3
   / \
  +   2
 / \
1   2
```

It's "backwards" because when you evaluate, you need to start by the bottom, where the 2 operands are known.

Answer (score 0):

So, for those that are interested.  I achieved what I was after by using the eval() function.  Although not the most robust, within the particular loop I have written the inputs are closely controlled so I am happy with this approach for now.